# how to reference a java .class file from a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have the JSP file (/page.jsp) in the root of my app directory.  I want to use this class located in  /WEB-INF/classes/Helper.class.

I tried using the JSP page import statment with the class name but that didn't work.  How can I reference Helper.class so that I can use it my JSP?  I don't want to include the class in a package/JAR.

Comment: Can you paste in the import statement you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I didn't know this until I looked it up. The [JSP Spec (JSP.11.2 JSP Page Implementation Class)](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html) is your friend. You'll need to move that class from the default package.

> As of JSP 2.0, it is illegal to refer
>   to any classes from the unnamed
>   (a.k.a. default) package. This may
>   result in a translation error on some
>   containers, specifically those that
>   run in a JDK 1.4 or greater
>   environment. It is unfortunate, but
>   unavoidable, that this will break
>   compatibility with some older JSP
>   applications. However, as of JDK 1.4,
>   importing classes from the unnamed
>   package is not valid (see
>   http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/compatibility.html#source
>   for details). Therefore, for forwards
>   compatibility, applications must not
>   rely on the unnamed package. This
>   restriction also applies for all other
>   cases where classes are referenced,
>   such as when specifying the class name
>   for a tag in a TLD

Answer (score 2):

If your class is located **directly** in `/WEB-INF/classes` that means it uses default package which is generally not recommended. You don't need to import it because of that; you can use it directly in your JSP:

```
<%
 Helper helper = new Helper(); // use appropriate constructor
 %>
```

A better solution would be to make it a part of package. You'd need to put it into appropriate subfolder of `/WEB-INF/classes` then, say `/WEB-INF/classes/com/mypackage/Helper.class`. You'll use fully qualified name or import it in your JSP:

```
<%
 com.mypackage.Helper helper = new com.mypackage.Helper(); // use appropriate constructor
 %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to call a static method of Helper but I get the error "Helper cannot be resolved"

Comment: This is the code that causes the error above:  Connection conn = Helper.getDBConnection(url,datasource);

Comment: @duffymo - I'm not in any way **recommending** someone to use scriptlets - I myself have long abandoned JSP altogether in favor of templating. But - guessing from `Helper.getDBConnection()` and default package - I'm thinking it'll be more helpful to OP if I were to answer his question rather than try and recommend he use Spring MVC or something :-)

Comment: What happens if you have two Helper classes and you make use of the first example?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in the CLASSPATH of your WAR - either a package under WEB-INF or JAR under WEB-INF/lib.  That's just basic Java.

The object has to be in request, page, session, or application scope.  This usually means that a servlet put it there.  You've got to have a servlet and JSP collaborating to do it.

You can write scriptlet code, but I think it's far better to use JSTL.  Scriptlet-free JSPs are a good idea in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The following has to work `<%@ page import="com.*" %>`.

Check the documentation of the J2EE container you are using. If you are using a J2EE Sun Certified Container you shouldn't have an issue with the page import directive.

See [JSP Directives](http://www.jsptut.com/Directives.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this: `<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>`

the above creates an instance of Date and adds it as the request attribute map key `now`. 
It is then available for use, just like any other request attribute variable, e.g., inside el expressions such as `${now.time}` will print the time in milliseconds.

So in your scenario, you'd do `<jsp:useBean id="Helper" class="com.your.company.name.Helper"/>`. Make sure Helper has a no arg public constructor.

extra info here http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html