# How to reference standard classes from JSP pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a simple JSP file in the WebContent folder of an Eclipse generated web project. I am trying to create a reference from this to a Test class but I keep getting a compilation error - "Test cannot be resolved to a type".

I tried to reference it by using:

```
Test t = new Test();
```

and then I added

```
<%@page import="Test"%>
```

and it still didn't work. So I tried to pre-compile the .java file, then I tried to copy it in the src folder, the WEB-INF/classes and the WebContent folders. Then I created a  WEB-INF/classes/actions folder and copied the class and source file there too. I tried to modify the import statement to reflect each of these locations but the compile was unable to find the class in either of them.

So, I'm running out of ideas. Where am I going wrong?

Ok solved it.
Here's what I was doing wrong: I blindly followed some old tutorial and copied the same pre-compiled file in places where it didn't belong. And the one time I copied it in the right place it didn't work because it didn't have the correct package declaration. What I did is I cleared out my project and let eclipse create packages in the right places and files with the proper declarations and it worked.

Comment: What package is the class in?

Comment: I haven't created any packages. I have just copied the class to the locations above.

Comment: Try putting it in some package and use the package name to refer to it while importing.

Comment: Its good to be use Package for putting your class, as Java is Package-Centeric language...  l
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1514968/1490962

Comment: I tried both those solutions and neither worked.

Comment: Is your class declared as public?